# why does java.util.Calendar.DATE represent "day of month"?

Tags: java, calendar

Well, I know that it represents the day of month but my question is why? Why not `Calendar.DAY` used to represent it? Is it because of poor naming of variables or is there an underlying reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are also other variables:

- `DAY_OF_MONTH`
- `DAY_OF_WEEK`
- `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`
- `DAY_OF_YEAR`

And the Javadocs for `DATE`:

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. **This is a synonym for DAY_OF_MONTH.** The first day of the month has value 1.

My guess as to why `DATE` is a synonym is that `DAY_OF_MONTH` was the most common field used, so it was made easier to type with `DATE`.

Also, the definition of "date" is "The day of the month or year as specified by a number." (according to Google)

Comment: I know, my curiousity was why it has stayed as "DATE".